# Unlocking and locking an account with tinyint field

Tags: php, sql

I have created a login attempt lockout system.

After 5 bad locking attempts within 24 hours in the `cms_login_failures`, a SINGLE entry should placed within `cms_user_lockout`, the code then checks that table to see if the account is locked or unlocked. When a user is placed into `cms_user_lockout`, the `tinyint` field should be set to **0** (locked for 48hrs) but if I change it to **1**, it should unlock.

My problem is that every bad attempt is now being logged into `cms_user_lockout` and the lockout itself is not being applied and the error:

```
$errors->defineError("locked_out", "Your account has been locked due to repeated login failures, please contact your administrator.", array());
```

is not being outputted.

Here are the code snippets for the lockout system, can somebody help me fix this?

```
$allowed_login     = 1;
            $qry_CheckDatabase = "  SELECT *
                                    FROM
                                        cms_user_lockout 
                                    WHERE
                                        culo_date_time >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 48 HOUR) 
                                    AND 
                                        culo_user_id = " . $db->SQLString($row->user_id) . "
                                    LIMIT 1
                                    ";
            $rs_CheckDatabase  = $db->query($qry_CheckDatabase);

            if ($rs_CheckDatabase->num_rows > 0) {
                $lockedOut     = $rs_CheckDatabase->fetch_object();
                $allowed_login = $lockedOut->culo_reactivated;
            }
            if (!$allowed_login) {
                $errors->defineError("locked_out", "Your account has been locked due to repeated login failures, please contact your administrator.", array());
            } else {
```

/*----------------------*/

```
if (!(isset($pw_ok) && $pw_ok)) {
                    $errors->defineError("invalid_user_pass", "Your username or password is invalid. Please try again.", array("username","password"));

                    if (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])) {
                        $str_RemoteHost = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                    } else {
                        $str_RemoteHost = '';
                    }
                    $qry_CheckDatabase = "  SELECT count(*) as login_failures
                                        FROM
                                            cms_user_login_failures
                                        WHERE
                                            culf_date_time >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
                                        AND 
                                            culf_user_id = " . $db->SQLString($row->user_id) . "";
                    $login_failures    = 0;
                    $rs_CheckDatabase  = $db->query($qry_CheckDatabase);
                    if ($rs_CheckDatabase->num_rows > 0) {
                        $rowCheck       = $rs_CheckDatabase->fetch_object();
                        $login_failures = $rowCheck->login_failures;
                    }

                    $qry_WriteToDatabase = "    INSERT INTO     cms_user_login_failures
                                                    (
                                                        culf_user_id,
                                                        culf_date_time,
                                                        culf_remote_host
                                                    )
                                    VALUES          (
                                                    " . $db->SQLString($row->user_id) . ",
                                                    Now(),
                                                    " . $db->SQLString($str_RemoteHost, true) . "
                                                    )";
                    $db->query($qry_WriteToDatabase);

                    if ($login_failures > 4) {
                        $qry_WriteToDatabase = "    INSERT INTO     cms_user_lockout
                                                        (
                                                            culo_user_id,
                                                            culo_date_time
                                                        )
                                        VALUES          (
                                                        " . $db->SQLString($row->user_id) . ",
                                                        Now()
                                                        )";
                        $db->query($qry_WriteToDatabase);
```

Comment: Side note; Why don't you extend your user-table with a column 'Locked'?

Comment: It was considered but the team decided against it.